# Compare histograms with different x-axis values

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am having some trouble working with Python histograms. I have 2 Bell curves with the same number of points but with dramatically different values for those points. I want to compare the shape of the curves. Plots 1 and 2 show what I am getting. I want it to look like plot 3 below, but not with points!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hist1 = np.random.normal(0,100,1000)
hist2 = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)

nBins = 100

plt.figure(1)
plt.hist((hist1,hist2),bins=nBins)

plt.figure(2)
plt.hist(hist1,bins=nBins)
plt.hist(hist2,bins=nBins)

plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(np.histogram(hist1,bins=nBins)[0],'o')
plt.plot(np.histogram(hist2,bins=nBins)[0],'o')
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot just go and compare them. One strategy would be to standardize both of them to a Gaussian distribution of mu=0 sigma=1. Maybe this could also help you to compare distributions https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zmap.html 
It is a more "fancy" way to compare, instead of using visuals. But in the end it is basically also using a standard normal. Although it has the option of placing two different distributions to compare, which could be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks, Ignacio. I did not know about this zmap!

Comment: Me neither, was looking for how to standardize arrays and found that and thought it could be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was indeed pretty simple.

Just had to standardize both functions before and plot them separately in the same figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hist1 = np.random.normal(0,100,1000)
hist2 = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)

nBins = 10

def Standardize(distribution):
    newDistribution = (distribution-np.mean(distribution))/np.std(distribution)
    return newDistribution


plt.figure(2)
plt.hist(Standardize(hist1),bins=nBins)
plt.hist(Standardize(hist2),bins=nBins)
```